# Can't we generate a true Ms-Excel file under LAMP?

Tags: php, excel, lamp

I am developing a project under LAMP, there is a situation to generate xls file from the system then it would be upload by users later.

While uploading the document it's type is ODS , so it could not be parse by the system.

What can i do to resolve this issue, kindly expect suggestions to you all.

Comment: i think that with this pear u can achieve it :
http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro-format.php

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to check "PHPExcel2007" a wonderful library to parse/write Excel Files (Formats from 5.0 - 2007). Works like a charme for us.

[PHPExcel2007](http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)

Comment: It is creates really MS Excel files. Not just a structured XML. It supports compression and customizations. It also supports exporting to PDF, HTML, CVS etc.